# Complex Equations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The Equation:

$$ z^{4} -2 z^{3} + 12z^{2} -14z + 35 = 0 $$

has a root with a real part 1, solve the equation.

When it says a real part of 1, does this mean that we could use (z-1) and use polynomial division to extract the other rots? Hence:

$$ (z^{4} -2 z^{3} + 12z^{2} -14z + 35 ) / (z-1) $$

But i don't get the right answer, any other approaches I should try?

Comment: You would divide by $z-1$ if $1$ was a root. But the information only says that one of the roots has real part equal to $1$, not that the root is itself $1$. Do you know what "real part" means?

Comment: Hint: have you tried factorizing the equation? What happens if you write $12z^2 = 5z^2 + 7z^2$?

Comment: I also thought of that, yes if z = a+bi , Real part is a and Imaginary part is b. So it should give us (1+bi)(1-bi), while its conjugate is also a root. Hence it I should divide it by 
$$ 1+b^{2} $$ instead of (z-1) ?

Comment: @Ara You should be able to divide it by $\left(z^2-(1+b^2)\right)$

Comment: Following up the hint of @blue, what would be the form of a root $z$ whose real part equals $1$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be z = 1+bi ? Because we don not know what the imaginary part is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a root of that equation of the form $1+ib$ then:

$$(1+ib)^4 - 2(1+ib)^3 -12(1+ib)^2-14(1+ib) + 35 = 0\Longrightarrow \\(1 + 4ib -6b^2 -4ib^3 + b^4) - 2(1 + 3ib - 3b^2 -ib^3) + 12(1 + 2ib - b^2) - 14(1+ib) + 35 =0 \Longrightarrow b^4-12b^2+32 + i(-2b^3+8b) = 0$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{cases}b^4 - 12b^2+32 = 0\\-2b^3+8b = 0 \end{cases}$$

From the second equation we can see that $b\in \lbrace -2,0,2\rbrace$.

But $b=0$ doesn't satisfy the first equation. The other two values do.

Therefore $(1-2i)$ and $(1+2i)$ are roots of the equation.

Comment: I understand your procedure but, but there is a solution though :/

Comment: @Ara I made a mistake copying the equation (I wrote $-13z$ instead of $-14z$). I've corrected the mistake and it should be correct now.

Comment: I can see it : Awesome, but a question. Could I insert 1-bi instead of 1+bi? Would it give the same answer? Ans also shouldn't we have 4 solutions?

Comment: @Ara Yes, note that our equation gave us the solutions $b = \pm 1$ so $-b = \mp 1$, i.e. the roots given are $1-2i$ and $1+2i$, if we had written $1-bi$ we would have got the roots $1+2i$ and $1-2i$.

Answer (score 1):

Since all coefficients are real, and $P(1)\neq0$, this means that we have two complex conjugate roots of the form $1\pm ai$, whose resultant quadratic is $z^2-sz+p$, where *s* and *p* are the sum and the product of the two roots. Can you take it from here ? ;-)

Comment: I get it I think, as I wrote on the comment above shouldn't I divide the equation with $$(1+b^{2})$$ ? But instead of z should I insert 1-bi or 1+bi?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so different from Lucian's approach, and may (or may not) feel computationally more straightforward.

This equation has real coefficients so that roots come in complex conjugate pairs. We are give that there are roots $z=1\pm bi$. Now let $y=z-1$ so that $z=y+1$ whence $$(y+1)^4-2(y+1)^3+12(y+1)^2-14(y+1)+35=y^4+2y^3+12y^2+8y+32=0$$ has the purely imaginary roots $y=\pm bi$

Putting this in and equating real and imaginary parts gives $$b^4-12b^2+32=0$$ and $$-2b^3+8b=0$$

The first equation factorises as $(b^2-4)(b^2-8)=0$ and the second as $-2b(b^2-4)=0$ so to be consistent we need $b^2=4$, $y=\pm 2i$ and $z=1\pm 2i$.

This gives the factorisation $$(z^2-2z+5)(z^2+7)=0$$ for the original equation, which enables the remaining roots to be found.

Comment: Awesome, so first we find out b. Hence we have two rots, due to the fact that we have conjugate pairs. So the other two will be calculated with polynomial division, the $$(z^{2}+7) $$